# Get font family name from a TTF file

Tags: php, fonts, truetype

I'm working with some TTF files in PHP. I'm using this to get some info out of those files: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

I was wondering if there is any way to get the font family name, by using that library or any other, because I haven't found much info about it.

As an example, let's say I have this two fonts TTF files: Roboto Light and Roboto Bold. What I want is to get "Roboto" which would be the family name of those fonts.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method named `\FontLib\Font::getFontName` in [php-font-lib](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib) that returns font family name.

```
$font = \FontLib\Font::load('./fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
$font->parse();
echo $font->getFontName();
// prints: Open Sans
```

**EDIT**

TTF file stores font family name inside the `name` table at the ID 1 ([as described here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-chapter08#3054f18b)). `FontLib` parses this table and returns you this value when you call `getFontName()` method. In your case your ttf file contains `Roboto Light` string in `Font Family Name` row. I suggest you to either use this value or strip the additional font characteristics from font name.

Comment: thanks for your answer. After loading this file: Roboto-Light.ttf if I call getFontName() I get: "Roboto Light" so it's not working as expected to return the font family "Roboto"... not sure why

Comment: @JVLobo, I have updated my answer. Looks like you should add a hack to replace available font characteristics from the font name.